# Initializing in Constructor

Tags: java, c++, constructor, initialization

I have seen lots of codes where the coders define an *init()* function for classes and call it the first thing after creating the instance.

Is there any harm or limitation of doing all the initializations in Constructor?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both Java and C++?  Deliberate?

Comment: no, but sometimes init is called to initialize after two different constructors - to avoid code pasting.

Comment: virtual init() can be used for polymorphic initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a design pattern that has to do with exceptions thrown from inside an object constructor.

In C++ if an exception is thrown from inside an object costructor then that object is considered as not-constructed at all, by the language runtime.
As a consequence the object destructor won't be called when the object goes out of scope.

This means that if you had code like this inside your constructor:

```
int *p1 = new int;
int *p2 = new int;
```

and code like this in your destructor:

```
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

and the initialization of **p2** inside the constructor fails due to no more memory available, then a bad_alloc exception is thrown by the **new** operator.
At that point your object is not fully constructred, even if the memory for **p1** has been allocated correctly.
If this happens the destructor won't be called and you are leaking p1.

So the more code you place inside the constructor, the more likely an error will occur leading to potential memory leaks.

That's the main reason for that design choice, which isn't too mad after all.

More on this on Herb Sutter's blog: [Constructors exceptions in C++](http://herbsutter.com/2008/07/25/constructor-exceptions-in-c-c-and-java/)

Answer (score 2):

Usually for maintainability and to reduce code size when multiple constructors call the same initialization code:

```
class stuff 
{
public:
    stuff(int val1) { init(); setVal = val1; }
    stuff()         { init(); setVal = 0; }

    void init()     { startZero = 0; }

protected:
    int setVal;
    int startZero;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just the opposite: it's usually better to put all of the initializations
in the constructor.  In C++, the "best" policy is usually to put the
initializations in an initializer list, so that the members are
directly constructed with the correct values, rather than default
constructed, then assigned.  In Java, you want to avoid a function
(unless it is `private` or `final`), since dynamic resolution can put
you into an object which hasn't been initialized.

About the only reason you would use an `init()` function is because you
have a lot of constructors with significant commonality.  (In the case
of C++, you'd still have to weigh the difference between default
construction, then assignment vs. immediate construction with the 
correct value.)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there's are good reasons for keeping constructors short and moving initialization logic into an `init()` method:

- constructors are not inherited, so any subclasses have to either reimplement them or provide stubs that chain with `super`
- you shouldn't call overridable methods in a constructor since you can find your object in an inconsistent state where it is partially initialized

Comment: Both of your arguments seem to argue against using an `init()` method.  Using `super` makes it clear that you are initializing the base class, `init` could be overridden.  And the fact that `init` could be defined in a derived class is a very, very strong argument against using it in a base class.

Answer (score 0):

It's a design choice.  You want to keep your constructor as simple as possible, so it's easy to read what it's doing. That why you'll often see constructors that call other methods or functions, depending on the language. It allows the programmer to read and follow the logic without getting lost in the code.

As constructors go, you can quickly run into a scenario where you have a tremendous sequence of events you wish to trigger. Good design dictates that you break down these sequences into simpler methods, again, to make it more readable and easier to maintain in the future.

So, no, there's no harm or limitation, it's a design preference. If you need all that initialisation done in the constructor then do it there. If you only need it done later, then put it in a method you call later. Either way, it's entirely up to you and there are no hard or fast rules around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple objects of the same class or different classes that need to be initialized with pointers to one another, so that there is at least one cycle of pointer dependency, you can't do all the initialization in constructors alone. (How are you going to construct the first object with a pointer/reference to another object when the other object hasn't been created yet?)

One situation where this can easily happen is in an event simulation system where different components interact, so that each component needs pointers to other components.

Since it's impossible to do all the initialization in the constructors, then at least some of the initialization has to happen in init functions. That leads to the question: Which parts should be done in init functions? The flexible choice seems to be to do all the pointer initialization in init functions. Then, you can construct the objects in any order since when constructing a given object, you don't have to be concerned about whether you already have the necessary pointers to the other objects it needs to know about.